# Best practices for weaning myself off of globals?

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables, global

I am self-taught (with a great deal of help from several books, tutorials, and forums), and I'm trying to wean myself off of using global variables.

Now when I want a variable to be "global-ish" (that is, I don't want to have to pass it explicitly from function to function), I create a class called Settings, which typically works as shown below.

Am I reinventing the wheel or is this an appropriate way to access program-wide variables without global pollution?  Is there a better / more pythonic way to accomplish this?

Any thoughts/advice would be appreciated.

```
class Settings():
    __current = None
    __old = []

    def __init__(self, setting1=None, setting2=None):
        print("\n++++ Initializing Settings ++++")

        self.__setting1 = setting1
        self.__setting2 = setting2

        if Settings.__current:
            Settings.__old.insert(0, Settings.__current)
        Settings.__current = self

    def setting1(self):
        return self.__setting1

    def setting2(self):
        return self.__setting2

    # etc. - several more methods to set/get/process settings

    @classmethod
    def current(cls):
        return cls.__current

    @classmethod
    def old(cls, index):
        try:
            settings = cls.__old[index]
        except IndexError:
            settings = None
        return settings

class Thing():
    list = []
    def __init__(self, name="Thing"):
        print("++ Initializing New Thing: {} ++\n".format(name))
        self.name = name

        s = Settings.current()

        print("Global-ish setting1: {}".format(s.setting1()))
        print("Global-ish setting2: {}".format(s.setting2()))

        try:
            print("  --> Previous Global-ish setting2: {}".format(s.old(0).setting2()))
        except AttributeError:
            print("  --> No previous settings")

        Thing.list.append(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    settings = Settings(setting1="BloopittyBloop", setting2="FlizzletyFlop")
    newThing = Thing(name="Thing1")

    settings = Settings(setting1="GarbGlat", setting2="FloorMullet")
    anotherNewThing = Thing("Thing3 ate Thing2")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the purpose of that `Settings` object. If you're doing it for your personal convenience to pass data around then that's the wrong reason. But if your application as various configuration settings / flags that are needed in various places then passing a `Settings` object around it a good idea: it makes it explicit where you're using settings and you (or other developers) can see where the `settings` object originally came from.

However, if your need access to certain variables but they don't really belong in a `Settings` object (they're part of something else) then you need to associate those variables with that other object. For example, if you have a desktop application and your `Settings` object contains all kinds of values that are needed in many places (GUI settings, database connection details, paths to files, etc..) then it may be better to create/load the settings/configuration and construct the appropriate objects (a `ApplicationWindow` class, a `Database` class, etc).

This means you're only passing the relevant details / objects around as opposed to the entire configuration file (settings) to every possible location in your code. This prevents you from accidentally using other settings that you don't really need and it keeps the code clean.